# Refresh View after use

Tags: java, android

When click TextView1 shown an image1 in AlertDialog
then click ok and  click TextView2 show image2 on the image1 ,i try that remove image1 when click TextView2 but Failed ...
what do shall ???

image.xml :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/l1"
>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center"
    >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/dialog_imageviewd"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    />
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/green"
        android:layout_below="@+id/dialog_imageviewd"

        >
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/dialog_textviewd"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:layout_below="@+id/dialog_imageviewd"
    />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

PageFragmane.java :

```
 public PageFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        view2 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.image, container, false);
        textViewd = (TextView)view2.findViewById(R.id.dialog_textviewd);
        imageViewd = (ImageView)view2.findViewById(R.id.dialog_imageviewd);
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.page_fragment_layout, container, false);
    }

     public void onViewCreated(final View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

     if(length>0)
                {
                    final String imagetxt=images[0];
                    final String t=t[0];

                textView1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        AlertDialog.Builder alertadd = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
                        textViewd.setText(t);
                        int id = getResources().getIdentifier(imagetxt , "drawable", getContext().getPackageName());
                        imageViewd.setBackgroundResource(id);
                        alertadd.setView(view2);
                        alertadd.setNeutralButton("ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface km, int am) {
                            }
                        });
                        if(view2.getParent()!=null) {
                            ((ViewGroup) view2.getParent()).removeView(view2);
                        }
                        alertadd.show();
                    }

                });

            }
        if(length>1)
        {
            final String imagetxt=images[1];
            final String t=t[1];

            textView2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    AlertDialog.Builder alertadd = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
                    textViewd.setText(t);
                    int id = getResources().getIdentifier(imagetxt , "drawable", getContext().getPackageName());
                    imageViewd.setImageResource(id);
                    alertadd.setView(view2);
                    alertadd.setNeutralButton("ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface km, int am) {

                        }
                    });
                    if(view2.getParent()!=null) {
                        ((ViewGroup) view2.getParent()).removeView(view2);
                    }

                    alertadd.show();
                }

            });

        }
}
```

Comment: I Solved it ! i use imageViewd.setBackgroundResource(id); and change to imageViewd.setImageResource(id); and the problem was solved !

Comment: please add your resolution as an answer and accept it - helps people in the future.